# Can't open classes in developer console

Tags: developer-console, platform-bug

We are not able to open and modify classes with Salesforce developer console. This restriction works also for another devs with system administrator profile. The message :

[image]

Has anyone seen this message before? What should be done? We haven't changed any setting in org.

@EDIT: I'm able to access classes from external editor like sublime, so it should not be problem with profile. I have also tried another computer with another browser.

Comment: Check your profile visualforce and class permissions.

Comment: i can access classes from external editor like sublime, so it should not be problem with profile.

Comment: @AlexanderAeonsTorn thank you for response, but im not trying to insert/update records

Comment: Clear cookies and browser settting....

Comment: @DOMINICEDWARD i tried it on another computer and it still doesnt work

Comment: Are you using the same credentials for both sublime and developer console? Worth checking.

Comment: Currently encountering this issue as well.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing on cs21. cs20 opens very slowly. Production version on na17 works well. Same company/org/setup.

Tried different orgs on cs5, cs31 and worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known Salesforce bug. It's affecting Summer '16 orgs with more than 2,000 Apex classes. If you go [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jknXQAQ), you can check the `This Issue Affects Me` button and Salesforce will notify you when it's resolved.